# How to extract a type from the scope operator at the compile time?

Tags: c++, templates

Is it possible (without using macros) to have a template parameter deduced by a compiler in a static function that takes no parameters?

```
struct Widget
{
    template<typename T = ?>
    static void foo()
    {
    }
 };

 struct Base : Widget {};
 struct Derived : Base {};

 Base::foo(); // T should be deduced as Base
 Derived::foo(); // T should be deduced as Derived
```

In my use case, writing `Base::foo<Base>();` would not only be redundant (the compiler already has that information, as I've already said `Base::`) but would also introduce a possibility to make a mistake - calling `Base::foo<SomeOtherType>();` should be disallowed.

Is there any way to distinguish, at a compile time, whether foo is called as `Base::foo()` or as `Derived::foo()`?

Comment: It looka like you need CRTP here.

Comment: @n.m. CRTP will not solve this for deeper hierarchies. I think adding something like this to the language can solve many annoying issues, like unique_ptr not workable with covariance. I'm referring to some hypothetical mechanism that automatically infers template type (of a method or inner class) in a base class based on subclass type.

Comment: I think the key issue here is that it will be always called as `Widget::foo`

Comment: Some information as to what the underlying problem is could help here. CRTP seems like a very good fit, depending on what you expect `foo` to to.

Comment: @super Basically I want the compiler to generate one `foo` for every class in the hierarchy. My original problem is using `enable_shared_from_this` with a class hierarchy. It doesn't work well - if a base class inherits `enable_shared_from_this<base>` then calling `shared_from_this()` inside a derived class will still return a `shared_ptr<base>`, not `shared_ptr<derived>`, which would be more useful. I tried to present a minimal example that showcases this problem.

Comment: @rubix_addict Maybe you should state in your question that the relation between `Base` and `Derived` is important to you. Because this is the part the will break when solving this with CRTP. Or directly use the `enable_shared_from_this` example because in that case it is more apparent.

Comment: One approach to a multi-level CRTP hierarchy like this is outlined in answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18174441/crtp-and-multilevel-inheritance).

Answer (score 1):

One approach to a multi-level CRTP hierarchy like this is outlined in answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18174441/crtp-and-multilevel-inheritance).

Another way to do this is with injected base classes every other layer.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

class WidgetBase
{
};

template <class D, class B = WidgetBase>
class Widget : public B
{
  public:
    static void foo()
    {
        std::cout << typeid(D).name() << " is " << sizeof(D) << " bytes large\n";
    }
};

class Base : public Widget<Base> { int a; };

class Derived : public Widget<Derived, Base> { int b; };

class MoreDerived : public Widget<MoreDerived, Derived> { };

int main()
{
    Base::foo();
    Derived::foo();
    MoreDerived::foo();
}
```